# - iOS : Make a tree based on a JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, algorithm, tree

In recent days, I'm facing a problem I can't solve.
Indeed, I have some data in a JSON. I parse this JSON and all is ok.

Here is the structure of this JSON:

```
{
    "obs" : [
    {
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Title": "Category 1",
        "Description": "Description 1",
        "ParentCategoryId": null
    },
    {
        "CategoryId": 2,
        "Title": "Category 2",
        "Description": "Description 2",
        "ParentCategoryId": null
    },
    {
        "CategoryId": 3,
        "Title": "Category 3",
        "Description": null,
        "ParentCategoryId": null
    },
    {
        "CategoryId": 4,
        "Title": "Category 1.1",
        "Description": "Description 1.1",
        "ParentCategoryId": 1
    },
    {
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Title": "Category 1.2",
        "Description": "Description 1.2",
        "ParentCategoryId": 1
    },
    {
        "CategoryId": 6,
        "Title": "Category 1.1.1",
        "Description": null,
        "ParentCategoryId": 4
    },
    {
        "CategoryId": 7,
        "Title": "Category 1.1.2",
        "Description": null,
        "ParentCategoryId": 4
    },
    {
        "CategoryId": 8,
        "Title": "Category 1.1.1.1",
        "Description": null,
        "ParentCategoryId": 6
    },
    {
        "CategoryId": 9,
        "Title": "Category 1.3",
        "Description": "Category 1.3",
        "ParentCategoryId": 1
    }

    ]
}
```

My model for these objects (.h) I'm using the librairie JSONModel:

```
@class CategoryModel;

@protocol CategoryModel @end

@interface CategoriesModel : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<CategoryModel> * obs;

@end

@interface CategoryModel : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * CategoryId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * Title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString<Optional> * Description;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber<Optional> * ParentCategoryId;

@end
```

Then, in a view controller, after get the data of the JSON and parsed it, I would like to make a NSDictionary, NSArray or something like that like a tree, to display these categories in a UITableView for example.

My probleme is: I can't find a solution to "sort" this data and make a tree with this.

Here my methods for now:

```
- (void)parseJSON
{
    NSError * error;
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"list" ofType:@"json"];
    NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    self.myJSON = [[CategoriesModel alloc] initWithString:jsonString error:&error];

    for(CategoryModel * obs in self.myJSON.obs)
    {
        if(obs.ParentCategoryId)
        {
            CategoryModel * parent = [self searchParentObjectForChild:obs];
            NSLog(@"Parent of %@(ID:%ld) : %@(ID:%ld)", obs.Title, [obs.CategoryId integerValue], parent.Title, [parent.CategoryId integerValue]);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@(ID: %@) doesn't have a parent",obs.Title, obs.CategoryId);
        }
    }
}

- (CategoryModel *)searchParentObjectForChild:(CategoryModel *)child
{
    for (CategoryModel * obs in self.myJSON.obs)
    {
        if(obs.CategoryId == child.ParentCategoryId)
        {
            return obs;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

**Notes:** if possible, don't change the structure of the JSON.

Please, if someone has a idea how I can achieve this, let me know. 
Any suggestions are welcome as well! 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you have an array of this class and want to build a new array from it :)

```
@interface CategoryModel

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * CategoryId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * Title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * Description;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * ParentCategoryId;

@end
```

First of all let's add another property to each category which will make your life a lot easier when you use the tree in your app logic.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* subCategories;
```

Now you might want to write something like this (please note that this might take a long time for a big number of categories so I prefer if you find a known algorithm to build your tree (maybe an AVL tree or something)) but everything shall be fine for hundreds of categories.

```
- (void)findCategoryChildren:(CategoryModel*)category fromArray:(NSMutableArray*)originalCopy currentIndex:(int*)i {
        for (int j = 0; j < originalCopy.count; j++) {
            CategoryModel* childCategory = originalCopy[j];
            if ([childCategory.ParentCategoryId intValue] == [category.CategoryId intValue]) {
                if (category.subCategories == nil) {
                    category.subCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                }
                [category.subCategories addObject:childCategory];
                [originalCopy removeObjectAtIndex:j];
                j--;
                i--;

                // Now find the childs of this child category
                [self findCategoryChildren:childCategory fromArray:originalCopy currentIndex:i];
            }
        }
    }

    - (NSArray*)sort:(NSArray*)original {
        // This is the final array (the tree)
        NSMutableArray* result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        // This is a copy of the input to minimize the time of the latter iterations
        NSMutableArray* originalCopy = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:original];
        for (int i = 0; i < originalCopy.count; i++) {
            CategoryModel* category = originalCopy[i];
            // This is a root category
            if (category.ParentCategoryId == nil) {
                [result addObject:category];
                [originalCopy removeObjectAtIndex:i];
                i--;

                // Now try to find its children
                [self findCategoryChildren:category fromArray:originalCopy currentIndex:&i];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! That help me :). But with this method, I get only the childs at one level: - Category 1 then Category 1.1 and 1.2, but childs of Category 1.1 and 1.2 are not listed. I'm trying to solve the problem...

Comment: Don't worry, you help me a lot and help me to understand how that works, so thank you ;)

Comment: Please check now :( sorry I don't have the time to test it thoroughly